Nestjs Type 'CreateUserInput' is not assignable to type '(Without<...> & UsersUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UsersCreateInput)'
I made a migration from string to string[] for the academicProgram field
model Users {
  userId          Float   @unique //since those are big integers, use float to not be limited in size!
  userEmail       String
  userName        String
  userLabels      String?
  country         String
  academicProgram String[] //it returns null sometimes, make it @default("")??

  //relations (to another model):
  answers Answers[]
}

This is my userservice. Everything is fine in dev mode. I can create users in db normally. The issue comes in deployment mode.
async create(createUserInput: CreateUserInput) {
    try {
      //the create command it does return the user created as compare to the createMany command
      const newUser = await this.prismaClient.users.create({
        data: createUserInput,
      });
      return newUser;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw Error(error);
    }
  }

Basically render throws this error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
src/modules/users/users.service.ts:27:9 - error TS2322: Type '{ country: string; userEmail: string; userId: number; userName: string; academicProgram: string[]; userLabels: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'UsersCreateManyInput | UsersCreateManyInput[]'.

  Type '{ country: string; userEmail: string; userId: number; userName: string; academicProgram: string[]; userLabels: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'UsersCreateManyInput[]'.

    Type '{ country: string; userEmail: string; userId: number; userName: string; academicProgram: string[]; userLabels: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UsersCreateManyInput'.

      Types of property 'academicProgram' are incompatible.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

27         data: createManyUsersInput.manyUsersInput.map((x) => ({
           ~~~~
  node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:4041:5
    4041     data: UsersCreateManyInput | UsersCreateManyInput[]
             ~~~~

    The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: UsersSelectCreateManyAndReturn<DefaultArgs>; data: UsersCreateManyInput | UsersCreateManyInput[]; skipDuplicates?: boolean; }'

It looks like it still working with the string field from previous migration.
But everything seems to be updated in the node_modules/prisma/client/index.d.ts file:
 /**
   * Users create
   */
  export type UsersCreateArgs<ExtArgs extends $Extensions.InternalArgs = $Extensions.DefaultArgs> = {
    /**
     * Select specific fields to fetch from the Users
     */
    select?: UsersSelect<ExtArgs> | null
    /**
     * Choose, which related nodes to fetch as well
     */
    include?: UsersInclude<ExtArgs> | null
    /**
     * The data needed to create a Users.
     */
    data: XOR<UsersCreateInput, UsersUncheckedCreateInput>
  }
  export type UsersCreateManyInput = {
    userId: number
    userEmail: string
    userName: string
    userLabels?: string | null
    country: string
    academicProgram?: UsersCreateacademicProgramInput | string[]
  }
  export type UsersCreateacademicProgramInput = {
    set: string[]
  }

Here is my migration file:
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "Users" DROP COLUMN "academicProgram",
ADD COLUMN     "academicProgram" TEXT[];

